# Critical css with Laravel elixir

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp, laravel-elixir

I´m using the gulp package [critical css](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical), previosly I install this package with:

```
 npm install --save critical
```

But after run `gulp --production`, the npm report me this error:

```
 mix.critical is not a function
```

this is my complete gulpfile code:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var BrowserSync = require('laravel-elixir-browsersync');
var critical = require('critical');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.styles([
        "bootstrap.css",
        "bootstrap-theme.css",
        "main.css",
        "jquery.fancybox.css",
        "font-awesome.css",
        ]).version("css/all.css")

    mix.critical({
        src: 'http://myapp.dev',
        css: 'public/css/all.css',
        width: 1280,
        height: 600,
        dest: 'public/css/critical.css'
    });

});
```

Why npm report me this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think critical is built into elixir<sup>1</sup>. You need to extend elixir with a [custom task](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir#extensions).

This will create a `critical` task:

```
var critical = require('critical');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('critical', function() {
  critical.generate({
    src: 'http://myapp.dev',
    css: 'public/css/all.css',
    width: 1280,
    height: 600,
    dest: 'public/css/critical.css'
  });
});
```

Then to add it to the default task, add this inside the main elixir call:

```
mix.task('critical');
```

When this is done, it will be executed when you run `gulp` or when you run `gulp critical`.

---

1. I'm going by looking through the [recipes folder in the repo](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/tree/fdffe4ae5ddab285775a7b180bcdf61e1f35cafb/src/tasks/recipes). The [`task.js` file](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/fdffe4ae5ddab285775a7b180bcdf61e1f35cafb/src/tasks/recipes/task.js) in particular mentions needing to extend elixir. If elixir does indeed have a built-in automatic extending of other modules ([besides the ones listed here](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/fdffe4ae5ddab285775a7b180bcdf61e1f35cafb/src/tasks/recipes/external-recipes.js)), please toss me a reference link and I'll look into it further.